# css filter:brightness vs position:sticky

Tags: html, css, sticky, css-filters

I have site with "LOGO" being `position: sticky` and "panel1" both are in the same parent of grid.

Everything works fine until i want to add `filter: brightness();` to anything on site (here "panel1"), sticky works but "LOGO" goes under other elements (run code to see what i mean).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: #A68555;
  font-family: Sarpanch;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.wrapper>div {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 99vw;
}

#logo {
  display: grid;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #456;
  padding: 2vw 0vw 2vw 0vw;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

#logo>div {
  display: grid;
}

#panel1 {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.naH_ee2KTP4lM8xvD0yobwHaCx%26pid%3DApi&f=1);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panels" id="logo">
    <div style="position:relative; width:40vw;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcarfinance.credit%2Fdist%2Fimg%2Fuser%2F3d-carousel%2Fcar.png&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:15vw;">
      <h1 style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">LOGO</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panels" id="panel1">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Filters create a new stacking context (as well as other properties like `transform`). Add some z-index to counter this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: #A68555;
  font-family: Sarpanch;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.wrapper>div {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 99vw;
}

#logo {
  display: grid;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #456;
  padding: 2vw 0vw 2vw 0vw;
  margin-top: 5%;
  z-index: 1; /* Add z-index, any positive integer (basically: not "auto") will pull this above */
}

#logo>div {
  display: grid;
}

#panel1 {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.naH_ee2KTP4lM8xvD0yobwHaCx%26pid%3DApi&f=1);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panels" id="logo">
    <div style="position:relative; width:40vw;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcarfinance.credit%2Fdist%2Fimg%2Fuser%2F3d-carousel%2Fcar.png&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:15vw;">
      <h1 style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">LOGO</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panels" id="panel1">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it's true that a stacking context is created but it's not the issue here. It's the painting order involved here. Filter change the order of when the element should be painted and both the sticky and the filtred element belong to the same stacking context